# inno setup : automatic rollback and restore application to previous state

Tags: inno-setup

We are planning to migrate our custom installer to innosetup / or any other 3rd party installers (InstallAware for e.g)

Among them, inno setup is our prime tool due to ease of use, maintenance and scripts (basically i am  Delphi programmer - So we found the scripts easy in innosetup)

Here, we wanted the complete rollback and switch our application to previous state if any errors at any stage. I checked various articles and QA in stack overflow and see that the above is not possible once installer completed the installation and any error encountered afterwards

We checked the following options also.
1) Custom backup and restore ==> Due to large number of files including large volume of databases, we are afraid that it will take more time to install

2) Install new version and then uninstall older version : Difficult also due to above + we are having many shared files and databases

Is there any alternatives ?

TIA
Venkatesan

Comment: How do you want to achieve a complete rollback without a complete backup?

Comment: You can use RAD & Installer (http://www.rad-installer.com) expert for Delphi to create Inno Setup installers directly in IDE (sorry for OT and little self promo).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, I wish to take the complete backup or atleast the files that are changed in the upgrade. For that we can use beforeinstall event in innosetup. I just wanted to know whether any straight forward method available for backup and restore

Comment: @Slappy, Thank you for your suggestions on rad-installer.com. Very good to see this. However we need to find out how it fits our installers. Becoz we use both the delphi + .net in our software.

Comment: `BeforeInstall` is probably the best approach.

Comment: i am thinking of using PrepareToInstall to take the backup of all the files. This way complete files will be backedup and ready for rollback in case of any issues.
Rollback will be done based on the setup exit code in the end / in one of the afterinstall events